# Couldn't connect containers using docker-compose.yaml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created two Dockerfiles to run frontend and backend in a web application. When I run docker-compose.yaml file, web application front-end is opened of web browser. But I cannot login to the system. I think there is a problem with connecting those containers. Following is my docker-compose.yaml file. What can I do to resolve this problem ?

```
version: '2'
services:
gulp:
  build: './ui'
  ports:
    - "3000:4000"

python:
  build: '.'
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `--links` to enable communication between containers and you should use their DNS network alias like `http://python:5000`

Answer (score 0):

Containers within a docker-compose file are part of one network by default. And one container can access other container using their host name.

Host name can be defined in docker-compose file using [hostname](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir). And if hostname is not defined, then the service name is considered the hostname.

Internally, docker containers can talk to each other by referring to each other at their hostname. Like in your case, gulp can access python at `http://python:5000` and that would be possible even if you did not declare ports. This all is happening all because it is internal to the docker system.

From outside, if you want to connect to any of  the services, then you can define `ports`, as you did and then access those services at the defined port number.